# Deleting From Sql Operation with c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm developing a hotel management system. I can add new guests successfully, but in the deletion operation, that doesn't work even if the code doesn't give any errors.

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/0lEl0R.png] : this is the screen of deletion

and code ;

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class deleteguest : Form
    {
        public deleteguest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Cem-Bilal;Initial Catalog=hocu;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();


        private void deleteguest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listele1();
        }

        public DataTable guest_id = new DataTable();
        public void listele1()
        {
            guest_id.Clear();
            baglanti.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Guest", baglanti);
            adapter.Fill(guest_id);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = guest_id;
            adapter.Dispose();
            baglanti.Close();
        }

        private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                if (baglanti.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    baglanti.Open();
                ds.Clear();
                SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Delete From Guest Where guest_id='" + txt_id1 + "'", baglanti);
                komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dataGridView1.Update();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                baglanti.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("The Existing Guest Has Been Successfully Deleted");
                listele1();
                txt_id1.Text = "";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    baglanti.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to never use `+` when building a sql query string, you should replace your string with a parameter.

Comment: Also, the problem is you did `txt_id1` when you should have done `txt_id1.Text`.

Comment: ohh, how did i miss that, Thank you so much for realizing it. It worked well.

Comment: how do i give you reputation here guys ? you cannot guess how much you helped me with it.

Comment: I voted to close your question because it is a simple typographical error. You can just delete the question or post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: you can also comment one more so that everyone can easily see it. Thus, you earn reputation.